# SSl-TLS encryption by a jdbc connector. Can I switch it off?

Tags: java, encryption, jdbc, mariadb, ssh-tunnel

Must connect to a MariaDB database through a SSH tunnel.
Use putty to open the tunnel with port forwarding and get error message
`RSA public key is not available client side (option serverRsaPublicKeyFile not set)`.
The database server provider does not support SSl/TLS encrypted messaging.
Apparently my jdbc-connector encrypts by default and I should switch that off.
But how?

Added `encrypt=false` in my Java code:

```
  url = "jdbc:mysql://" + databaseURI.trim() + "/" + databaseSchema+ "/encrypt=false";
  connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, databaseUserName,
                    databasePassword);
```

as advised by my database server provider
but that had no result.

Comment: Surely it should be `?encrypt=false`?

Comment: what does `select version();` show?

Comment: And are you sure this isn't an `ssh` error? And what does 'that had no result' actually mean?

Comment: I suspect the SSH isn't impacting this and the RSA public key is a MySQL behaviour that MariaDB doesn't implement. I suggest using [MariaDB Connector/J](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/installing-mariadb-connectorj/), and [SSL and MariaDB connector J](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/using-tls-ssl-with-mariadb-java-connector/)

Comment: @danblack Never seen that message from SSL. Looks like ssh to me.

Comment: Looks a bit like [this](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/issues/6589)

Comment: @danblack OK so that shows it is an authentication error over an existing connection, whether SSL or not. It’s not an SSL error.

Comment: Where do you see the error? Share the log

Answer (score 1):

MySQL's default authentication method is caching_sha2_password which requires a RSA public key. The RSA public key is either stored on client machine or can be retrieved from the server during connection handshake.

Since the second option is less secure, MySQL's JDBC driver disables this option by default. To enable retrieval of RSA public key you have to append `allowPublicKeyRetrieval=True` to your connection url.

I wonder why this question is tagged as mariadb, since MySQL JDBC connector is used on client side and obviously MySQL on server side (MariaDB doesn't offer authentication method which requires a RSA public key).

Comment: Thanks, I added allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true.

Comment: Thanks. It worked but now I get java.sql.SQLInvalidAuthorizatiionSpecException. Possibly caused by worong characterEncoding